# How to fix libQt5WebKit symbol lookup error?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, qt5, bin

My lab is using Avizo as an image processing software. To install it on one's computer, the software is embedded in a .bin file.

The official installation manual states to just execute it as a superuser and everything should be fine.

However, as the supported Linux distro is CentOS and not Ubuntu/Debian, few dependencies were missing but could easily be installed via `apt-get`.

As the software is installed in `/usr/local/`, when I try to execute it I get the following output:

> /usr/local/Avizo/2020.2/bin/arch-LinuxAMD64-Optimize/Avizo: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/Avizo/2020.2/bin/arch-LinuxAMD64-Optimize/../../lib/arch-LinuxAMD64-Optimize/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined symbol: UCNV_FROM_U_CALLBACK_ESCAPE_50

I tried to install again `libqt5webkit` & `libqt5webkit-dev` and that didn't have any noticeable effects.

What does that symbol lookup error mean?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the ICU library (Unicode helpers) are either missing, installed in the wrong place or do not go well together with the binaries you have. Make sure that the ICU library is compiled with the same settings as the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed Amira 2020.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. Avizo and Amira are from the same vendor and have large parts of code in common, so the following hints may help:

- install the package icu4c-50-2. I fetched the sources from GitHub, as the version in the Ubuntu 20.04 repo was too new and would't work with Amira
- install openssl-1.0.0. The openssl version in the Ubuntu 20.04 repo is 1.1 which did not work for Amira 2020.2. I installed it from the sources.
- place the extra libraries in some directory and include it in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable (some people will find this insecure, but Amira itself uses LD_LIBRARY_PATH) or modify the start script that comes with the package accordingly

There is another issue with Amira and possibly Avizo, if you work with the Gnome Display Manager and Xorg as X11 Server. At startup the software will always look for a file /var/log/Xorg.0.log, but for gdm you have a display number 1 (or even higher), and the Xorg logfile is not in /var/log anymore, which results in error messages. Despite the error Amira will start, but I did not test if further problems arise from this, as you can avoid these problems by using lightdm instead of gdm.